# Laravel 5: Odd "Undefined Variable" error when returning a defined array to View

Tags: php, laravel

As the title states, I'm getting an odd error in Laravel 5. I'm new to Laravel, and this week I dived into Jobs/Queues. I've gotten an "Undefined Variable: $errors" error in the past, and that one I was able to understand and fix. But now, I can't seem to get past this one. To my knowledge, everything looks fine. The following breakdown will (hopefully) give you an idea of what I'm doing/where the error happens:

```
class PostFormFields extends Job implements SelfHandling
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

/**
 * The id (if any) of the Post row
 */

protected $id;


/**
 * List of fields and default value for each field
 */

protected $fieldList = [
    'title' => '',
    'subtitle' => '',
    'page_image' => '',
    'content' => '',
    'meta_description' => '',
    'is_draft' => '8',
    'publish_date' => '',
    'publish_time' => '',
    'layout' => 'blog.layouts.post',
    'tags' => [],
];


/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function __construct($id = null)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

 /**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $fields = $this->fieldList;

    if($this->id)
    {
        $fields = $this->fieldsFromModel($this->id, $fields);

    } else {
        $when = Carbon::now()->addHour();
        $fields['publish_date'] = $when->format('M-j-Y');
        $fields['publish_time'] = $when->format('g:i A');
    }

    /**
     * Populate with old values, if they exist
     * @var [type]
     */
    foreach ($fields as $fieldName => $fieldValue)
    {
        $fields[$fieldName] = old($fieldName, $fieldValue);
    }

    $fields = array_merge($fields, ['allTags' => Tag::lists('tag')->all()]);

    return $fields;
}
```

Above is the code inside the handler function of my Job class, the file it sits in is called PostFormFields.php. It's job, essentially, is just to return an array filled with all the values pertaining to a post, based on the Post Model and what's in the database that pertains to that specific Post ('title','content',etc) if a user's entered them in the past

```
  public function create()
{

    $data = $this->dispatch(new PostFormFields());
    $data['title'] = 'testing';
    var_dump($data);

    return view('admin.post.create', $data);
}
```

Above is the code inside my PostController class, in the create() method. As you can tell, I'm using a resource controller for my Post Controller. It dispatches the PostFormFields Job and stores all the returned data in an array $data. However, since the create() method will be used to create a new post, only the keys should be returned, with values set to their default value ''.

This works. As you can see, i run a 'var_dump()' on the variable $data to see what, if anything, is returned. I then pass the $data array to the create View. This is where the error comes up.

[Laravel "Undefined Varieble" Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDRCu.jpg)

Above is a picture of the error I get when I try to access the /create route. It's clear that the $data does have the $title variable defined, as well as all the other keys in the array. Why am I getting an "Undefined Variable" array when I clearly have it defined by the time it's sent to the create View?

The line of code is says the error is in is the following:

```
<input type="text" class="radius" name="title" id="title" value="{{ $title }}">
```

Comment: You are passing an array but trying to call a variable. If you change {{ $title }} to {{ $data['title'] }} does it work?

Comment: It reports an error in `_form.blade.php`. How and where do you include this template part?

Comment: @CanCelik doing that gives me another error: `Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'`. Isn't passing arrays to views and accessing the key/value pairs within them pretty commonplace in Laravel?

Comment: @mirzap `_form.blade.php` is a partial that i include via `@include()` in the `create.blade.php` parent view file. The `_form.blade.php` should, theoretically, inherit the variables accessible by it's parent view, no?

Comment: @jactorrez are you missing $ before the 'data' ? it should be value="{{ $data['title'] }}"

Comment: @CanCelik he is doing right. when you passing an array to the view, then you have all array keys available as variables in the view. So, there should be a varaiable $title and you can not access it via $data['title'], but calling it directly $title.
@jactorrez I'm trying to reproduce this, but have no luck. I'm passing an $data array as you do, I'm calling the $title inside `_form.blade.php` and I have `@include('_form')` in the `create.blade.php` and everything works fine to me :S

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass that array to view via compact function of laravel. So that you can use it in view as you want.
Please check about compact here - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phps-compact-pros-and-cons?page=1

```
public function create()
{

    $data = $this->dispatch(new PostFormFields());
    $data['title'] = 'testing';
    var_dump($data);

    return view('admin.post.create', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: What you are doing with compact is that you pass $data variable to the view. An then you access the title as @CanCelik suggested - `$data['title']`. However, if you pass an array, then you have all array keys available as variables.